# Conditional operations without using SWITCH CASE

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select, oracle12c

I have a couple of complex tables. But their mapping is something like:

**TABLE_A**:

```
_________________________________
|   LINK_ID     |   TYPE_ID     |
_________________________________
| adfasdnf23454 |   TYPE 1      |
| 43fsdfsdcxsh7 |   TYPE 1      |
| dfkng037sdfbd |   TYPE 1      |
| sd09734fdfhsf |   TYPE 2      |
| khsadf94u5dfc |   TYPE 2      |
| piukvih66wfa8 |   TYPE 3      |
_________________________________
```

**TABLE_B**:

```
_____________________________________________
|   LINK_ID     |  CODE_ID  | CODE_VALUE    |
_____________________________________________
| adfasdnf23454 |    7      |   test 1      |
| fgubk65esdfj7 |    6      |   test 2      |
| ooogfsg354fds |    7      |   test 3      |
| sd09734fdfhsf |    5      |   test 4      |
_____________________________________________
```

The *LINK_ID* column links these two tables.

My requirement is to have all the records from *TABLE_A* checked whether they have a specific *CODE_ID* or not.

1. If the record has *CODE_ID* as 7 - populate *CODE_VALUE* in a column.
2. If the record has *CODE_ID* as 6 - populate *CODE_VALUE* in another column.
3. If the record doesn't have a *CODE_ID* show *CODE_VALUE* as null.

The catch is, *TABLE_B* may have records that *TABLE_A* don't. But the final result should contain the records of *TABLE_A* alone.

*PS*: SWITCH CASE not suggested since I would require the fields in the same row. (Please see the multiple rows for same *LINK_ID* in *OBTAINED RESULT* on using SWITCH CASE)

**OBTAINED RESULT**:

```
_______________________________________________
|   LINK_ID     | CODE_VALUE_1 | CODE_VALUE_1 |
_______________________________________________
| adfasdnf23454 |   test 1     |    null      |
| adfasdnf23454 |   null       |    test 4    |
| sd09734fdfhsf |   test 6     |    null      |
_______________________________________________
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**:

```
__________________________________________________
|   LINK_ID     | CODE_VALUE_1  |   CODE_VALUE_2 |
__________________________________________________
| adfasdnf23454 |   test 1      |   test 4       |
| 43fsdfsdcxsh7 |   null        |   null         |
| dfkng037sdfbd |   null        |   null         |
| sd09734fdfhsf |   test 6      |   null         |
| khsadf94u5dfc |   null        |   null         |
| piukvih66wfa8 |   null        |   null         |
__________________________________________________
```

Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option uses two correlated subqueries:

```
select
    a.link_id,
    (select code_value from table_b b where b.link_id = a.link_id and b.code_id = 7) code_value_1,
    (select code_value from table_b b where b.link_id = a.link_id and b.code_id = 6) code_value_2
from table_a a
```

Note that this assumes no duplicate `(link_id, code_id)` in `table_b`. You could also write this with two `left join`s - which is quite the same logic.

Another solution is a single `left join`, then conditional aggregation:

```
select  
    a.link_id,
    max(case when b.code_id = 7 then b.code_value end) code_value_1,
    max(case when b.code_id = 6 then b.code_value end) code_value_2
from table_a a
left join table_b b on b.link_id = a.link_id and b.code_id in (6, 7)
group by a.link_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Problematic part of your question is what to do if two entries in B have same link_id and type_id. You can use min, max, last entry (but for that you need ordering column in B). Or you can list them all:

```
select * 
from a left join b using (link_id) 
pivot (listagg(code_value, ', ') within group (order by code_value) 
       for code_id in (6 as code6, 7 as code7))
```

Data:

```
create table a (link_id, type_id) as (
  select 'a', 'TYPE 1' from dual union all
  select 'b', 'TYPE 1' from dual union all
  select 'c', 'TYPE 1' from dual union all
  select 'd', 'TYPE 2' from dual );

create table b(LINK_ID, CODE_ID, CODE_VALUE) as (
  select 'a',    6, 'test 1' from dual union all
  select 'a',    7, 'test 2' from dual union all
  select 'a',    7, 'test 3' from dual union all
  select 'b',    7, 'test 4' from dual union all
  select 'd',    6, 'test 5' from dual );
```

Result:

```
LINK_ID  TYPE_ID  CODE6     CODE7
a        TYPE 1   test 1    test 2, test 3
b        TYPE 1             test 4
c        TYPE 1
d        TYPE 2   test 5
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fe84f7c07956852f4fd98f54a871b997)